# Active Directory - authentication fails

Tags: active-directory

I am trying to make an authentication using this code:

```
public IEnumerable<string> SearchADUsers(string username)
{
    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://rhc.local");

    DirectorySearcher dSearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

    entry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Delegation;

    foreach (SearchResult sResultSet in dSearch.FindAll())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetProperty(sResultSet, "cn"));
    }
    return null;
}
```

but I am getting an error :

> 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E8, comment: In order to perform this
>   operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data
>   0, v1db1

Comment: Why are you setting the AuthenticationType?

Comment: thank you it is resolved now